# How to accurately measure the time taken by a stored procedure/function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following options

1. Use the 'Include Client Statistics' option in SSMS . (I take the 'Wait time on server replies' to be the time taken by the stored procedure)
2. Capture the start and end time and take the diff.

This is what i do ,

```
DECLARE @startTime DATETIME
    SET @startTime = GETUTCDATE()

   EXEC MyStoredProc

  PRINT 'Execution Time : ' +  CAST(DATEDIFF(ms,@startTime,GETUTCDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' milliseconds'
```

But I sometimes see a big difference between the values I get from both the methods for the same stored procedure that I am beginning to think that I am doing something wrong here. Which method should I use? or is there a better way to time the stored proc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you run the following to get a good baseline everytime:

```
CHECKPOINT
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
```

[Stolen from here.](http://abemiester.com/abemiester/post/Setting-up-your-testing-environment-when-performance-tuning-SQL-Scripts.aspx)

Otherwise you might be pulling cached data.

Comment: +1. Thanks for pointing that out. But what i really wanted to know is 'Which of the 2 methods i have mentioned in my question is the most accurate' (assuming that i have cleaned out the cache as you have suggested)

Comment: I'm not sure, I would use `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` instead of either  those methods.  I'm guessing client statistics is better but i'm not sure.